# Create JSON data programmatically from API results in Swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am making a request to an API with the following json payload:

```
var json: [String: Any] = [
    "locations": [
        [
            "latitude" : 10,
            "longitude": 10,
        ],
        [
            "latitude" : 20,
            "longitude": 20,
        ]
    ]
]
```

Now, the above json is hardcoded so I could test the response from the API. The API in question returns elevation data.

However, the issue I have is that I do not want to hardcode the json payload, I need to populate the json with other data I get from a separate API that offers me lat/lon coordinates.

How can I populate the json with the lat/lon results I retrieve from the separate API?

Comment: Trying to figure out why this question has been downvoted. Nothing quite like someone downvoting and then not offering up a reason as to why! Hiding behind anonymity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Encodable` structs that model the JSON:

```
struct Locations: Encodable {
    let locations: [Location]
}

struct Location: Encodable {
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
}

let locations = Locations(locations: [
    Location(latitude: 10, longitude: 10), 
    Location(latitude: 40, longitude: 40)
])

do {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    let data = try encoder.encode(locations)
    // use `data` as the payload to send to your server
    print(String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Gereon, I don't think I would have figured this out by myself. This is exactly what I need ;-)